Generador xbase version 7.5
mas que duda o pregunta es un pedido... alguien tiene el instalador del generador "xbase" de la version 7.5? y si tuviera un update también en el download center ya no existe y necesito hacer unas modificaciones de un sistema muy antiguo con el que cuento. Saludos!

Estas seguro que la version es 7.5?. El ultimo generador xBase que veo esta en los instaladores de Gx 7.0
